# How to use a processor to dynamically remove/edit properties from views in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, preprocessor, post-processor

I have a web application made in sencha extjs 4.0.7, and i want it to have a different behavior when its oppened in a mobile browser. 
V.G. I would like to remove/edit all the labels in the app based on the mobile browser without have to edit all the application.

I've tried to use the pre/post processors to access the view items but with no success.

```
Ext.Class.registerPreprocessor('test', function(cls, data, callback) {
    if(data.$className.indexOf('.view.') != -1 && ('items' in data))
    debugger;
}, true).setDefaultPreprocessorPosition('test', 'first');


Ext.ClassManager.registerPostprocessor('test1', function(cls, data, callback) {
    if(data.$className.indexOf('.view.') != -1 && ('items' in data))
    debugger;
}, true).setDefaultPostprocessorPosition('test1', 'first');
```

The processors stops on the debugger statements but the objects dont have a items property.

Comment: Can you post which version of ExtJS you're using?

Comment: Update. The extjs version is the 4.0.7

Comment: @JoãoGomes Did you see my answer? Does it answer your question? Please comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that the name of the preprocessor is supposed to be the name of the property (from the prototype) that you want to preprocess.

```
Ext.Class.registerPreprocessor('title', function(cls, data) {
    data.title = data.title + ' Changed';
});   
Ext.Class.registerPreprocessor('html', function(cls, data) {
    data.html = data.html + ' Changed';
});  

Ext.define('MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel', 
    title: 'Here it is',
    html: 'Something'
});

Ext.define('MyPanel2', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel', 
    title: 'Here it is again',
    html: 'Something else'
});
```

See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/n35

The documentation seems really out of date (there's no callback as the doc and my initial comments stated). It is a private method, so it's likely to break as new versions come out.

I don't think this a good way to implement what you'd like, you're abusing what preprocessors are meant to do because you're not using it as intended. I think it will be much more maintainable if you do re-architect. I'd suggest you create a file with all the labels

```
var LABELS = { label1: 'desktop 1', label2: 'desktop 2' };
```

And load a different file for the mobile version. Your classes will just reference the LABELS object.

```
Ext.define('MyPanel2', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel', 
    title: LABELS.label1,
    html: LABELS.label2
});
```

My experience is that these attempts to minimize changes with hacks make for code that future maintainers will cuss you for.

Comment: This is it! Although it doesnt work for some properties like tooltips. Thank you.

Comment: @JoãoGomes Please don't solve your problem this way... One place will have to have intimate knowledge about all classes.